# Oracle Optimization - Update and Subquery

Tags: oracle

I have two very large tables (one with over 500 M records and the other with over 1B records)

I need to update status of the record in table one if one of the fields in table two contains more than 4 Char(10) characters in a row.

When I look for the records that meet that criteria it takes approximately 10 min -

```
SELECT B.ID as main_id
FROM Table A, TABLE B
WHERE A.CREATED_DATE > TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
AND   A.STATUS_CODE = 'IN PROGRESS'
AND   A.ID = B.ID
AND   (REGEXP_COUNT(B.TEXT, CHR(10) || '{4},1,'mn')) > 0
```

Now, I need to look up all of the records in table A and update status field to FAIL based on the query above.  Basically I am suing above as a sub-query for the update.  However, when I do that, my update statements run for a very long time where I would expect it to run slightly longer than 10 minutes (above query returns only 2 records back).  Here is what I have -->

```
MERGE INTO TABLE A
USING (SELECT B.ID as main_id 
  FROM Table A, TABLE B
  WHERE A.CREATED_DATE > TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
  AND   A.STATUS_CODE = 'IN PROGRESS'
  AND   A.ID = B.ID
  AND   (REGEXP_COUNT(B.TEXT, CHR(10) || '{4},1,'mn')) > 0) CHECK_ERRORS
ON (A.ID = CHECK_ERRORS.main_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.STATUS_CODE = 'FAILED'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered doing this in PL/SQL and then get trace to analyze errors?

Comment: Can you show us the execution plan of both the standalone query and the merge statement?

Comment: Maybe you could try the following ; change the MERGE query to : UPDATE A SET STATUS_CODE='FAILED' WHERE ID IN ( <Your original select query>) and specify a /*+ PUSH_SUBQ */ Hint. By default Oracle will try to execute the subquery the latest possible. The hint is to "force" him to execute the subquery the earliest possible as it reduces drastically the number of rows to update. Not sure about the result but worth trying

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is that you are unnecessarily joining the first table twice: once in the subquery (which already does the work needed in `MERGE`) and again in the `ON` clause of `MERGE`.

The `MERGE` statement should be something like this:

```
merge into table_a a
  using table_b b
   on ( a.id = b.id )
when matched then update 
  set a.status_code = 'FAILED'
  where a.created_date >    trunc(sysdate - 1)
    and a.status_code  =    'IN PROGRESS'
    and b.text         like '%' || chr(10) || chr(10) || chr(10) || chr(10) || '%'
;
```

It will also help speed up the processing if you had indexes on the `id` columns in both tables, and perhaps also on `created_date`, assuming only a small fraction of rows fall within the last day or so.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Wouldn't it be faster to use `B.TEXT LIKE '%'||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||'%'` instead of `REGEXP_COUNT`?

Admittedly, I don't use MERGE very often, but if you're just doing updates, I would write the second statement like this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.STATUS_CODE = 'FAILED'
WHERE A.CREATED_DATE > TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
  AND A.STATUS_CODE = 'IN PROGRESS'
  AND A.ID IN (SELECT B.ID FROM B WHERE B.TEXT LIKE
    '%'||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||'%');
```

(I'm assuming based on your code that you meant the Table 2 field contains 4+ CHR10 characters, not "more than 4")